# MySql sort by result from a function

Tags: mysql

Lets say i have a SQL table and i want to sort it by the results of a calculation.

```
 ID   user_id   field_id  value
 10      1         11      name 1
 11      1         12      13.22333    // A
 12      1         13      45.3322     // B
 13      2         11      name 2
 14      2         12      120.99      // A
 15      2         13      99.343      // B
```

I have my sql function like this

```
   calc(float A,float B) {
     return A*B;
   }
```

I have to sort users based on the return value from calc where:

```
  A=value when field_id=12
  B=value when field_id=13

  select * from table order by calc(A,B)
```

Does anybody know the correct MYSQL syntax?

The output is a list of user_id, that are sorted using the calc function

Comment: Can you please share expected output?

Comment: The output is a list of user_id, that are sorted using the calc function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a self join:

```
 SELECT A.user_id, calc(A.value, B.value)
 FROM table as A
 JOIN table as B
   ON A.user_id = B.user_id
 WHERE A.field_id  = 12
   AND B.field_id  = 13
 ORDER BY calc(A.value, B.value)
```

Using a single call:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (
     SELECT A.user_id, calc(A.value, B.value) as Total
     FROM table as A
     JOIN table as B
       ON A.user_id = B.user_id
     WHERE A.field_id  = 12
       AND B.field_id  = 13
) as T
ORDER BY Total
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks, but do you know if calc is called twice? The actual calc function does a lot of complicated calculations which may take a long time, is there a way to call it only once per sql statement?

Comment: yes, right now do calc twice. But I add the other calc just for testing. Do you need return the calc value or just the sorting?

Comment: no need to return calc just the sorted list of user_id based on the calc values

Comment: Then just remove the first calc ;)

Comment: You mean return and sort with a single call? Yes, I do. But you say you didnt need it doh.

Comment: Check edit. Test both version, second should be faster, but depend on data size index and other factors.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same without using `function` as well.

**Solution 1**

```
 SELECT A.user_id, A.value * B.value as calculatedVal
 FROM table as A
 JOIN table as B
   ON A.user_id = B.user_id
 WHERE A.field_id  = 12
   AND B.field_id  = 13
 ORDER BY (A.value * B.value)
```

**Solution 2**

```
 SELECT A.user_id, A.value * B.value as calculatedVal
 FROM table as A
 JOIN table as B
   ON A.user_id = B.user_id
 WHERE A.field_id  = 12
   AND B.field_id  = 13
 ORDER BY calculatedVal
```

Comment: Thanks, good answer, but the real calc function is very complicated so its not easy to make it inline.